# Visual Studio 2019 - issue with removing references

Tags: xamarin.forms, reference, xamarin.ios, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2019 still recognizing and building with references that are no longer present on the project.
This would not be an issue if I did not need to wrap the app without an AppConnectSDK that keeps popping up even thou I've deleted every reference of it from my project.
[image]

Even with no references and dependencies showing I sill get AppConnectSDKBinding.dll in my release folder and with my wrapper recognizing it.

I've tried also looking for SDK and editing in, but to no avail:

1. [project_name].iOS.csproj.user
2. [project_name].iOS.csproj
3. AssemblyInfo (in project folder under iOS project)
4. [project_name].csproj.user (this is Xamarin forms project)
5. [project_name].csproj
6. AssemblyInfo (in project folder under 'forms' project)

Comment: Close visual studio,go to the project folder and delete .vs folder, and obj folders and debug and release folders. open and rebuild project

Comment: @SupunLiyanaarachchi, could you please answer my question with your answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: If you are using version control, clone your project to another directory. This will recreate the correct dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Close visual studio,
2. go to the project folder
3. delete **.vs** folder
4. delete all content in the **bin** folder (**debug** and **release** folders)
5. delete obj folders
6. apply this to **xamarin.forms**, **xamarin.ios**, and **xamarin.android**
7. open and rebuild project